# Why does $stmt->execute always return true?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Even if the entered `id` isn't recognized, `$stmt->execute` still returns true, and therefore the program never outputs "Wrong ID or Password!". What am I doing wrong?

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$pwd = $_POST["pwd"];

include("./sql/connect.php");

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM list WHERE id = :id AND pwd = :pwd");

$stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
$stmt->bindValue(":pwd", $pwd);

if($stmt->execute()){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo $row["name"];
    }
}else{
    echo "Wrong ID or Password!";
}
```

Comment: Why should it __not__ return true?

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. You should use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: No `return` here - Only `echo`, do you want to check if no rows were return maybe?

Comment: $stmt->execute() `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure`. a bad ID without anny matches will still execute correctly... read http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: A query that returns zero rows is not an error, it's just an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not fail it returns 0 results, so `$stmt->execute()` will return true in that case. A simple workaround is passing your result to an array and check if it is empty or not.
Check out `Example #2 Counting rows returned by a SELECT statement` in [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) it explains why you should not use rowCount for a `SELECT` and a simple way to do the same thing but by using a second query for counting returned rows first. Personally i would not use a second query so here is the edited example.

```
if($stmt->execute()) {
    $out = [];
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $out[] = $row["name"];
    }
    if(empty($out)) {
       echo "no matching user is found";
    } else {
       // rest of your code
    }
} else {
    return $db->errorInfo();
}
```

PS: I have to thank the down-voter on this. Thanks, the answer really needed editing.